# Switching Class Animation Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to integrate this(http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/) with css and jquery ui in a different methodology. So far i'm trying the switch class method of jquery ui, however the duration of effect thing, the 3rd parameter, is not working or i understood that thing falsely.

```
$('.grayscaled').hover(function () {
    $(this).switchClass( "grayscaled", "nongrayscaled", 1000);
}, function () {
    $(this).switchClass( "nongrayscaled", "grayscaled", 1000);
});
```

I've created the fiddle for what i've done

http://jsfiddle.net/vLLgb/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to .grayscaled:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms;
```

Comment: Add: -moz-webkit-transition: all 1000ms;